# How to post true value in an array instead of key in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a PHP beginner. When I practice with `$_POST`, I want to post a true value such as date 1 instead of key 0. For example, when I choose date 1 and submit, it will print "You born date 1" instead of "You born date 0" because of array key. I tried `array_flip` but failed. Can't anyone help me, please?

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $date = $_POST['Ngay'];
            $month = $_POST['Thang'];
            $year = $_POST['Nam'];
            $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
            $hidden = $_POST['hidden'];

          echo "You born $date, $month, $year. Gender is $gender";
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        function build_form($value){
            foreach ($value as $k => $v){
                echo "<option value = '{$k}'>".$v."</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        $month = array(
            1 => "Thang 1",
            2 => "Thang 2",
            3 => "Thang 3",
            4 => "Thang 4",
            5 => "Thang 5",
            6 => "Thang 6",
            7 => "Thang 7",
            8 => "Thang 8",
            9 => "Thang 9",
            10 => "Thang 10",
            11 => "Thang 11",
            12 => "Thang 12",
            );
        $date = range(1,31) ;
        $year = range(1990,2000);
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name = "Ngay">
            <option>Choose date</option>
            <?php
                build_form($date);
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name = "Thang">
            <option>Choose month</option>
            <?php
            build_form($month);
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name = "Nam">
            <option>Choose year</option>
            <?php
                build_form($year);
            ?>
        </select>

        <select name = "Gender">
            <option>Gender</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="id=1">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original range() array has a number index. This number index is later the variable $k, when you build your form. So, either change the array or the way you build the form.

1) You might try array_combine() to only get the values of the array on both sides, looks a bit scary, like so:

```
    $date = array_combine( array_values(range(1,31)), range(1,31));
    $year = array_combine( array_values(range(1990,2000)), range(1990,2000));
```

2) You could also alter the build_form function and use `echo "<option value = '{$v}'>".$v."</option>";` - two times with values.

```
echo "<select>";
$range = range(1,12);
foreach ($range as $value) {
  echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: thanks for your support :)